# jQuery clone() form submit dont work as supposed

Tags: jquery, html, clone

When I clone a form and want to submit cloning form it submit parent form.
I update the question.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('body').on('click','input[type="submit"]',function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log($(this).closest('form'));
                        $(this).closest('form').submit();
                     });
             $('#clone').click(function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       $('#myform_1').clone(true).prop('id', 'myform_2' ).appendTo('.clone');
                     });
             $('[id^="myform_"]').each(function(key, form) {

                 $(form). validate({ //intit plugin
                    rules: {
                        field1: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        field2: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) { 
                        alert('valid form submitted'); 
                        return false; 
                    }
                });
             });
         });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zMYVq/552/

Comment: Please format and indent your code in a reasonable, consistent way when asking for help, it's very hard to read as-is. (It's a good idea to do that *anyway*.) (I've done it for you on this occasion.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24637173/2181514 "Even if you used a class instead, the various jQuery Validate methods cannot be attached to selectors that target more than one element at a time. So again, even if your target correctly selected a group of elements, only the first instance would be used."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery validate doesn't work with multiple forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635559/jquery-validate-doesnt-work-with-multiple-forms)

Comment: I change code according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/24637173/2181514 but still dosen't work correct http://jsfiddle.net/zMYVq/551/

Comment: You missed the relevant part of that answer: *even if your target correctly selected a group of elements, **only the first instance would be used**.* - **element** (not form).

Comment: I'm attaching validation to form one by one in .each()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click','input[type="submit"]',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log($(this).closest('form'));
                $(this).closest('form').submit();
             });
     $('#clone').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#myform_1').clone(true).prop('id', 'myform_2' ).appendTo('.clone');
             });

     $(".submit").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().validate({
            rules: {
                field1: {
                    required: true
                },
                field2: {
                    required: true
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) { 
                alert('valid form submitted formId='+$(form).attr("id")); 
                return false; 
            }
        }); 
     });

});
```

I have just assigned a class to your submit button

```
<div class="cl">
<form id="myform_1">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        function onValidate(val){

           $('#'+val).each(function(key, form) {

                 $(form).validate({ //intit plugin
                    rules: {
                        field1: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        field2: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) { 
                        alert('valid form submitted'); 
                        return false; 
                    }
                });
             });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
        var i=1;
            $('body').on('click','input[type="submit"]',function(e) {  
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).closest('form').submit();

                     });
             $('#clone').click(function(e) {
                       e.preventDefault();
                       i++;

                       $('#myform_1').clone(false).prop('id','myform_'+i ).appendTo('.clone');
                       onValidate( 'myform_'+i);

                     });


          onValidate("myform_"+i);
         });
```